# Compile correcty Connector 1.1.7 in debug mode for .pdb with VS2010

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Correct setting for compile on debug mode with VS2010 x86 ?

i have set this:

```
set MYSQL_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7
set BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS=C:\local\boost_1_61_0
and used this command:
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10 2010"
```

i'm using cmake version 3.13.2

```
But it show:
-- Looking for strtold
-- Looking for strtold - not found
-- Looking for strtol
-- Looking for strtol - found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - not found
-- Looking for strtoul
-- Looking for strtoul - found
-- Looking for strtoull
-- Looking for strtoull - not found
-- Looking for strtoimax
-- Looking for strtoimax - not found
-- Looking for strtoumax
-- Looking for strtoumax - not found

and:
CMake Warning (dev) in driver/CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0022 is not set: INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the link
  interface.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
```

what is missing ?

Comment: Regarding the warning, you might take a look at this: [cmake CMP0022](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0022.html). I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: "not found" just means that corresponded function is not implemented by the given compiler (Visual Studio 10 in your case). It doesn't prevent the project to be built. So, what is a **problem**?

Comment: yes I compiled them thanks they were in the folder \driver\Debug but without 2 sub-projects PACKAGE and INSTALL